# Python errors out with "You must specify two command line arguments"

Tags: installation, python

I have an anaconda install for Python.  When I fire up python and attempt to import packages this happens.

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas as pd
Error: You must specify two command line arguments
```

This information might be useful

```
(base) MAC:Fri Feb 14:09:32:~> python --version
Python 3.7.6
(base) MAC:Fri Feb 14:09:32:~> conda --version
conda 4.8.2
(base) MAC:Fri Feb 14:09:32:~>
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Do you have a file in your current directory named `pandas.py`? That would mask the real module.

Comment: I ran find and can only find pandas.py in the anaconda subtree.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks; see my answer below.  This is an ugly cautionary tale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happened. IN my home directory I had a program named `copy.py,` which was an example I use for teaching fileIO; it copies a file.  It takes two command-line arguments and errors out if the user fails to supply them.

Evidently, there is a module named copy that `pandas` uses.  My copy.py got seen prior to the system's and it created this mess.

Thanks, @jordanm, you provided the hint that helped me to see this.